# GCC Compiler Warning: extended initializer lists only available with c++0x

Tags: c++, gcc, warnings

Using this member initialization...

```
StatsScreen::StatsScreen( GameState::State level )
    : m_Level( level ) {
  ...//
}
```

I get the following warning...

`extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x`

Any information regarding this warning?

Edit: Warning went away after I removed one of the member that was assigned to a value inside the constructor (couldn't be done through member initialization) and made it a local variable instead of a class member. Still want to know what that warnings means though.

Comment: Does the GameState::State object have a copy constructor?  Or maybe m_Level isn't the exact same type as GameState::State.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are initializing the object with `{...}` instead of `(...)`:

```
StatsScreen ss{...}; // only available in C++0x
StatsScreen ss(...); // OK in C++98
```

To compile your code as C++0x code, just add the following flag when compiling:

```
g++ test.cpp -std=c++0x
```

Comment: One of the member in the constructor was initialized that way (however, it wasn't in the member initialization list) and that was the one I removed, so that makes sense.