# Warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x

Tags: c++, matrix

I tried declaring a matrix and when I compile I get this:

```
extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x
```

And when trying another solution I get this:

```
ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'A' (line 16)
```

Here is the code of my last try:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int m, l;

ifstream MatrixA ("A.txt");
MatrixA >> m;
MatrixA >> l;

int A [m][l];

for (int lineA = 0; lineA <= m; lineA++)
{
    for (int colA = 0; colA <= l; colA++)
    {
        A [lineA][colA];
    }
}

cout << "Matrix A: " << A[m][l] << endl;

return 0;

}
```

Comment: could you provide the compiler flags?

Comment: if you want to use c++11 features you'll need to put one of the following flags on the command line (depending on your compiler version): `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11`. declaring a c-style array with variable dimensions is indeed illegal in c++, as the error correctly implies.

Comment: as other comments have stated you can;t use variables. A new c++ 11 feature is `constexpr` which evalueates at compile time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCC Compiler Warning: extended initializer lists only available with c++0x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863827/gcc-compiler-warning-extended-initializer-lists-only-available-with-c0x)

Comment: The code you showed does not give the error in the question title. Please don't ask about an error for one piece of code and then show a different piece of code. Either show both, or just ask about one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ does not support built-in arrays of variable size. If you need variably sized array dimensions you'll need to use something which does the necessary memory allocations dynamically. A relatively straight forward alternative is to use a `std::vector` of `std::vector`s:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > A(m, std::vector<int>(l));
```

Comment: He could also use `constexpr` which evaluates at compile time.

Comment: @KostasRim: given that the matrix dimensions are first read, I'm not sure how `constexpr` is going to help here.

Comment: instead of reading the values from a file. he could use them as `constexpr`.

Comment: @KostasRim: sure. That solves a different problem, though. As coded in the question it seem the problem is: read a matrix with flexible dimensions which are given first. Use of `constexpr` doesn't help with this problem while the use of `std::vector` does (of course, there are also alternatives but I don't see any alternative using `constexpr`).

Comment: Yes, but that likely defeats the point of storing the dimensions in the file in the first place.

Comment: @DietmarKühl my bad there. I wanted to provide a different approach that's all. Thank thought :)

Comment: Yes, as stated by @DietmarKühl, the idea is to read the dimensions from a file. The dimensions are given in the first two lines of said .txt file (500x510 for A and 510x520 for B), but for some reason it won't work. In the second exercise I am supposed to do this dynamically as well

Comment: @Bruncky: you read two integers in a row. That only works if they are separated by whitespace. You'll need to read on integer, the sparator, and then the other integer (and, of course, verify the read operations are successful).

Comment: @DietmarKühl: I just used 'cout' to see what the values for 'm' and 'l' are and they are correct (500 and 510, respectively) when I run it. So I think it did manage to read it, but doesn't correctly put it into the matrix. Should I edit the post with the latest version of my code and what I get when running it?

Comment: @Bruncky: it seems the original question (why doesn't this code compile?) is actually answered (because it tries to use variable sized arrays which do not exist in C++). Rather than editing the question to become a different you'd ask a different question..l